# Clicking on load more adds 9 more JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

So I've got this script:

```
<script>
    var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams";
    $.getJSON(twitchApi, function(json) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            var streamGame = json.streams[i].game;
            var streamThumb = json.streams[i].preview.medium;
            var streamVideo = json.streams[i].channel.name;
            <!-- var streamViewers = json.streams[i].streamViewers; -->
            var img = $('<img style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" src="' + streamThumb + '"/>')
            $('#twitch').append(img);
            img.click(function() {
                $('#twitch iframe').remove()
                $('#twitch').append('<iframe src="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=' + streamVideo + '"></iframe>');
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

And I want to make that once you click on let's say #load ( which is an image ) or on a button or whatever, it adds +9 items from the JSON. How can I modify the code to get the onClick action which calls for another 9 items from the JSON?

Comment: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?offset=9

Comment: Alternatively just use the `next` value from the `_links` property in the returned data.

Comment: But how can I make it that onClick it displays (gets from the JSON)  +9 thumbnails. @Andy

Comment: But how can I make it that onClick it displays (gets from the JSON) +9 thumbnails. @James Lalor

Comment: As Andy said, use the next value, store it in a variable, and make a button with `$().click` or `$().on('click'`